# Pegar valor de elemento data-cod

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, script

Como faço para pegar o valor do elemento data-cod?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.chatUsuariosLista').click(function() {
    $("#para").val(this.id);


  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="1" data-cod="21321321" class="row chatUsuariosLista">Nome 1</div>

<div id="2" data-cod="54654655" class="row chatUsuariosLista">Nome 2</div>

<div id="3" data-cod="79879878" class="row chatUsuariosLista">Nome 3</div>

<br>

<input id="para" type="text" value="">
<input id="projeto" type="text" value="">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tens de usar a API [`.data()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/) do jQuery, ou a nativa [`.dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset).

Com jQuery seria: `var data = $(this).data('cod');`
Com JavaScript nativo seria: `var data = this.dataset.cod;`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.chatUsuariosLista').click(function() {
    $("#para").val(this.dataset.cod);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="1" data-cod="21321321" class="row chatUsuariosLista">Nome 1</div>
<div id="2" data-cod="54654655" class="row chatUsuariosLista">Nome 2</div>
<div id="3" data-cod="79879878" class="row chatUsuariosLista">Nome 3</div>
<br>
<input id="para" type="text" value="">
<input id="projeto" type="text" value="">
```